# Inverse of a matrix using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'd like to use numpy to calculate the inverse.  But I'm getting an error:

```
'numpy.ndarry' object has no attribute I
```

To calculate inverse of a matrix in numpy, say matrix M, it should be simply:
`print M.I`

Here's the code:

```
x = numpy.empty((3,3), dtype=int)
for comb in combinations_with_replacement(range(10), 9):
   x.flat[:] = comb
   print x.I
```

I'm presuming, this error occurs because x is now flat, thus '`I`' command is not compatible. Is there a work around for this?

My goal is to print the INVERSE MATRIX of every possible numerical matrix combination.

Comment: commented on the other answer also, but you have to defined x as a matrix `np.matrix(x)` so that the `.I` method is available.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The `I` attribute only exists on `matrix` objects, not `ndarray`s. You can use [`numpy.linalg.inv`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.inv.html#numpy.linalg.inv) to invert arrays:

```
inverse = numpy.linalg.inv(x)
```

Note that the way you're generating matrices, not all of them will be invertible. You will either need to change the way you're generating matrices, or skip the ones that aren't invertible.

```
try:
    inverse = numpy.linalg.inv(x)
except numpy.linalg.LinAlgError:
    # Not invertible. Skip this one.
    pass
else:
    # continue with what you were doing
```

Also, if you want to go through all 3x3 matrices with elements drawn from [0, 10), you want the following:

```
for comb in itertools.product(range(10), repeat=9):
```

rather than `combinations_with_replacement`, or you'll skip matrices like

```
numpy.array([[0, 1, 0],
             [0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: 'Module' object has no attribute inv ... =/

Comment: Yeah I tried that, I get the 'singular matrix' error. O_O

Comment: @JakeZ: That's because you're trying to invert uninvertible matrices. For example, one of the matrices you're generating is the 0 matrix.

Comment: Amazing! I completely forgot to check for singular matrixes -_-' Haha, thank you. worked like a charm.

Comment: The psudoinverse, done by `np.linalg.pinv` allows for inverting a singular matrix.  The Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse, for example, adds a *dampening factor* (just a identity matrix * k, where k << 1).

Comment: @Roman, your method doesn't work for `x = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)` square matrix, as `print(np.dot(x, inverse))` should be identity matrix, which it isn't! in other words `dot(a, ainv) = dot(ainv, a) = eye(a.shape[0]).`

Comment: @user2357112, Could you explain why I am able to compute the inverse of `x = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)` but `x = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)` and`x = np.a/range(16).reshape(4,4)` when all there are square matrices, I am getting `Singular matrix` error for last 2 arrays but not for 1st.

Comment: @anu: That's a linear algebra issue, not a programming issue. As a matter of linear algebra, your first matrix is invertible and your other two are not. There is no reason to expect all square matrices to have an inverse.

Comment: @user2357112, ah!, but here in [numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.inv.html), it says `Given a square matrix a, return the matrix ainv satisfying dot(a, ainv) = dot(ainv, a) = eye(a.shape[0]).`, I gave a square matrix, then why isn't returning me the inverse of it. Also, if all square matrices aren't invertible then could you please point me to a resource where I can learn about which all matrices can be reversed & which aren't(both theoretical & programming standpoint)? Also, what's the Linear Algebra issue, I didn't completely get that?

Comment: @anu: I think your best course of action here is to just take a linear algebra class.

Comment: @user2357112, thanks for suggestion!, will catch here soon!

Answer (score 26):

Another way to do this is to use the [numpy `matrix` class](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) (rather than a numpy array) and the `I` attribute. For example:

```
>>> m = np.matrix([[2,3],[4,5]])
>>> m.I
matrix([[-2.5,  1.5],
       [ 2. , -1. ]])
```

Comment: I'd rather this method since it's more straight forward. But both of them work exactly the same.

Comment: Though convenient, the use of `np.matrix` is discouraged officially since it leads to ambiguity for `np.array` users: [scipy.linalg](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/linalg.html#numpy-matrix-vs-2-d-numpy-ndarray)

Comment: It's also being deprecated: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html#numpy.matrix

Answer (score 14):

**Inverse of a matrix using python and numpy:**

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> b = np.array([[2,3],[4,5]])
>>> np.linalg.inv(b)
array([[-2.5,  1.5],
       [ 2. , -1. ]])
```

Not all matrices can be inverted. For example [singular matrices are not Invertable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> b = np.array([[2,3],[4,6]])
>>> np.linalg.inv(b)

LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

**Solution to singular matrix problem:**

try-catch the Singular Matrix exception and keep going until you find a transform that meets your prior criteria AND is also invertable.

Answer (score 3):

What about [inv](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.inv.html#numpy.linalg.inv)?

e.g.:
    my_inverse_array = inv(my_array)

Comment: I tried but i get the 'Singular Matrix' error...most likely because its flattened.... I wonder if theres a way to reshape it back to its original state and then inverse it?

Comment: It might be easier to stash its original state and then refer back to it, as with an object that contains the current state and an attribute that says what it was originally. numpy.linalg.lstsq will attempt to give you a least-squares solution, but I don't know of anything especially clean.

Answer (score 2):

IDK if anyone already mentioned this but I want to point out that matrix_object. `I` and `np.linalg.inv(matrix_object)` don't give a true inverse. This has given me a lot of grief. It's true that for a matrix object `m`, `np.dot(m, m.I) = an identity matrix`, but `np.dot(m.I, m) =/= I`. Same goes for `np.linalg.inv(I)`.

Be careful with that.