# Don't understand this AttributeError with inverse of a matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, matrix-inverse

I write a little program about the linear regression. However, there is a mistake that I can't find why. The program is below:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
X, Y = load_svmlight_file(r"C:\Users\asus\Desktop\data.txt")
trainx,testx=train_test_split(X,shuffle=False)
trainy,testy=train_test_split(Y,shuffle=False)
traverse_trainx=trainx.T
#闭式解
temp1=(traverse_trainx*trainx).I
temp1.I
```

And the mistake is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-130-92af132d9e41> in <module>()
      8 traverse_trainx=trainx.T
      9 #闭式解
---> 10 temp1=(traverse_trainx*trainx).I
     11 temp1.I
     12 

G:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py in __getattr__(self, attr)
    684             return self.getnnz()
    685         else:
--> 686             raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
    687 
    688     def transpose(self, axes=None, copy=False):

AttributeError: I not found
```

Comment: There's `.T` for the transpose, but why are you thinking there's a `.I` for the inverse? The error is saying that doesn't exist for that matrix type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inverse of a matrix using numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638895/inverse-of-a-matrix-using-numpy)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to find a matrix inverse, you'll have to use a function like [numpy.linalg.inv](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.inv.html) or [scipy.linalg.pinv2](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.pinv2.html).

The error you're getting is because there's no .I attribute on your array.

Comment: When I use numpy.linalg.inv. The resule is "0-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional"........However, the matrix is 13*13 size

Comment: `load_svmlight_file` loads the data into X as a scipy sparse matrix. You might try converting it to dense matrix first, like `X.todense()` before applying the inverse. Else there's [`scipy.sparse.linalg.inv(X)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.inv.html) you can use.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I tried the todense() function. It makes sense!